# Limit countries shown in checkout shipping to countries assigned in shipping zones settings?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, shipping, addresses

Is there a way to restrict the list of countries available in the checkout shipping address select menu to the countries assigned in the shipping zones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to either

1) Delete all the countries you don't use within your site in `commerce > settings > countries`.

2) Simply hide them in twig with something like this:

```
{% set allowedCountryIds = [1,3,4,6,7] %}
{% for key, country in craft.commerce.countriesList %}
  {% if key in allowedCountryIds %}
    <option value="{{ key }}">{{ option }}</option>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```